# Проиграть всю музыку в папке(абсолютный путь)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Возможна ли реализация через pygame или другие библиотеки python данной задумки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все довольно просто, получаете все файлы из папки, к примеру MP3-Файлы

как пример

```
import glob

txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
    txtfiles.append(file)
print(txtfiles)
```

далее, загружаете первый файл из списка

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
```

получаем окончание проигрыша файла `pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent()` и после стартуете следующий.

Весь список функционала тут 
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html